# Type reference without full namespace

Tags: typescript

There are two typescript files:

```
A.ts:

export class Person {
    public name:string;
    constructor(){}
}
```

and

```
B.ts:

import A = module("A");
var p: A.Person;
```

So far everything works fine.

However, when I try to make a shortcut for the type name imported from the A.ts :

```
var Person = A.Person;
var pp: Person;
```

the compiler complains (on the line: "var pp: Person"):

> > The name 'Person' does not exist in the current scope

How can I achieve this or similar syntax, to avoid long namespaces?

Comment: I don't know how to achieve what you're trying to do, however the problem you're getting with your shorthand notitation is that Person is not a TypeScript type but a reference to a class. Hence instead of writing `var pp : Person;` you could use `var pp = new Person();`

Comment: So, I can create an instance of the class but I can not declare a variable of the class. The compiler will be able to infer the type for the variable in one case and unable to do it in the other. It seems to me a bug in the compiler.  Anyway the second example ('var pp = new Person();') does work. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In TypeScript, the type annotation has to relate to a type known to the compiler. You can't just use variables as types. The alias you give to a module is the one you specify in the `import` statement - so you can alias from a long namespace to a short alias here:

```
import alias = module("My/Long/Module/Path");
```

But you *do* then have to use the alias.

To get the result you are looking for, you would have to use the slightly crazy local class extending the module class method:

```
import myModule = module("MyModule");

class Person extends myModule.Person {
}

var x: Person;
```

Comment: Extending the class is a bit too much for my purposes. I will stick with alias. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the error you ***should*** get is "Type not defined" However currently the error is "The name does not exist in the current scope". Its because of separate declaration spaces for variables and types. A variable cannot be referenced in a type name section.

You can see it in a simple single file case here :

```
module M
{
    export interface P {}
}

import im = M; 
var foo1:im.P; // Okay 

var vm = M;
var foo2:vm.P; // Error
```

However the solution to reduce the number of letters is inheritance as Steve mentioned.