# TypeScript "use"/alias for Classes

Tags: class, module, alias, typescript

Is there a way to do an alias or "use" (like PHP) for a TypeScript class/module.

Example:

If I have:

```
module Foo {
    class Bar {}
}
```

Normally I have to write `Foo.Bar` to use it outside of the module. Is there a way I can alias that to something else, like "FooBar".

This would be really useful if you have several submodules (which my current project does), like:

module A.B.C.D {
       export class E {}
   }

is normally `A.B.C.D.E` which is silly.

Comment: I think you'll find the answer on this possible duplicate: [Type reference without full namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541843/type-reference-without-full-namespace)

Comment: It's not completely what I was looking for, but I think it's probably the answer I'm getting, so I've marked this duplicate too. Thanks. =p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to page 82 of the old Typescript language spec, it stated that the following is possible.
So you should be able to alias "use" a module without having to reference the entire hierarchy.

```
module A.B.C
{
  import XYZ = X.Y.Z;

  export function ping(x: number) {
    if (x > 0) XYZ.pong(x – 1);
  }
}

module X.Y.Z
{
  import ABC = A.B.C;

  export function pong(x: number) {
    if (x > 0) ABC.ping(x – 1);
  }
}
```

The new Typescript language spec covers similar material in the section on [Import Alias Declarations](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#103-import-alias-declarations)